# Smaller VARCHAR column on MySQL better for indexing?

Tags: mysql

If a column that is indexed in a MySQL table with the data type `VARCHAR(255)` can be brought down to say, `VARCHAR(10)`, how much can that possibly improve performance for queries?

The `key_len` gets reduced if you take a look at an `EXPLAIN` statement, but I still don't have enough data/insight to understand how much of a performance improvement, if any at all, this would have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the most basic optimizations is to design your tables to take as little space on the disk as possible. This can give huge improvements because disk reads are faster, and smaller tables normally require less main memory while their contents are being actively processed during query execution. Indexing also is a lesser resource burden if done on smaller columns.

MySQL supports a lot of different table types and row formats. For each table, you can decide which storage/index method to use. Choosing the right table format for your application may give you a big performance gain. See Chapter 8, "MySQL Storage Engines and Table Types."

You can get better performance on a table and minimize storage space using the techniques listed [here:](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/MySQL-Optimization-part-2/1/)
One of them is:
The primary index of a table should be as short as possible. This makes identification of each row easy and efficient.